PyQt5, How to make each object's color different?
I want to make a window with three Scroll Areas, and change their colors
class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):

        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1024, 768)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #19191A;")
    
    ...
    scroll_area_1 = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll_area_1.setGeometry(120, 100, 300, 600)
        scroll_area_1.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll_content_1 = QWidget()
        scroll_area_1.setWidget(scroll_content_1)
        scroll_area_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #201F22;"
                                    "border-width: 0px;"
                                    "border-radius: 15px;")
        grid_1 = QGridLayout(scroll_content_1)


But this scroll area color doesn't changed, area's color following window color.
How can I change color of scroll area?

To change the color of the QscrollArea set the style sheet for the scroll area's viewport:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QScrollArea, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow)"
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()
    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1024, 768)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #19191A;")
        scroll_area_1 = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll_area_1.setGeometry(120, 100, 300, 600)
        scroll_area_1.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll_area_1.viewport().setStyleSheet("background-color: #201F22;")
        scroll_content_1 = QWidget()
        scroll_area_1.setWidget(scroll_content_1)
        scroll_area_1.setStyleSheet("border-width: 0px; border-radius: 15px;")
        grid_1 = QGridLayout(scroll_content_1)

Repeat for other scroll areas.
Hope it helps you 

@user24097842
Glad I could help . Do not forget to mark it as correct so people with the same issue as you can find answer to their problem .

Generic properties should always be avoided for complex widgets and containers. A more appropriate way for the above would use QScrollArea > #qt_scrollarea_viewport > QWidget { background: ...; } QScrollArea > #qt_scrollarea_viewport { border-width: ...; }, all set on the scroll area, and possibly QMainWindow { background: ... } on self.setStyleSheet().
